# Aligning two elements to the center

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

How can I make "question" vertically center-aligned with "answer-text", but not with "submit-answer-button"?

[image: This is what I'm looking for]

```css
.question-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.answer-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
  <div class="question-container">
    <div id="question">6 x 2</div>
    <div class="answer-container">
      <input type="text" id="answer-text">
      <button id="submit-answer-button" onclick="submitAnswer()">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Where in the HTML is the "6 x 2" seen in the image?

Comment: That is "question", the script generate random numbers and it display it in "question"

Comment: I've edited the code to make it more understandable.

Comment: Wrap the question div and the answer-text input in the same element, or use CSS Grids to define those areas.

Comment: FYI, your input lacks a label, which is poor practice and an accessibility problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to change the html, you can use `grid-template-columns: subgrid;` to `.answer-container`. For example, like this:

```css
.question-container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
}

#question {
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap; /* optional */
  border: dashed 1px red; /* testing */
}

.answer-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-template-columns: subgrid;
}

.answer-container input {
  min-width: 0; /* srinking */
}

/* just for centering */
body {
  display: grid;
  min-height: 100dvh;
  margin: 0;
  place-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="question-container">
  <div id="question">6 x 2</div>
  <div class="answer-container">
    <input type="text" id="answer-text">
    <button id="submit-answer-button">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's perfect, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Just put the question `div` and the answer `input` in the same `div` and give it the same style as the main container `container-1`:

```js
function submitAnswer() {
    let answer = document.getElementById("answer-text");
    if (parseInt(answer.value) == 12) {
        console.log("Correct");
    } else {
        console.log("Incorrect");
    }
}
```

```css
.container-1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
.container-2 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
#submit-answer-button {
    margin-top: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-1">
    <div class="container-2">
        <div class="container-1">
            <div id="question">6 X 2</div>
            <input type="text" id="answer-text">
        </div>
        <button id="submit-answer-button" onclick="submitAnswer()">
            Submit
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked too, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Basically what I did here is put everything in row-directed flexbox, and added two children each represent a column.

Finally, I set alignment to the left column, so it is centered.

```css
.root-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: end;
}

.left-col {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="root-container">
  <div class="left-col">
    <div id="question">4+2</div>
    <input type="text" id="answer-text">
  </div>
  <div class="right-col">
    <button id="submit-answer-button" onclick="submitAnswer()">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked too, thank you!